# How to display PHP session variables in HTML page?

Tags: php, html

How can I display a PHP session variable in an html file? I am redirecting users to random html pages without repetition, and for each page they see I would like the page number to increase by 1. I've started a session on the PHP file that succeeds the first HTML page and I have this PHP session variable:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION[$pagenum]))
{
    //New user
    $_SESSION[$pagenum] = 1;   
}

$_SESSION[$pagenum]++;
```

Is this the correct way to store a session variable that increases by 1? After this, I would like to display the value of the variable **$_SESSON[$pagenum]** in the title of my html pages.

Comment: The same way you display any other variable in a web page, with `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but looking at your code I guess that your variable `$pagenum` does not exist. The $_SESSION is just like an array, so use an unique string to assign something, e.g. `$_SESSION['pageNumber']`. Also in this case you cannot miss the else, or the starting value will be 2. So your code would become:

```php
if(!isset($_SESSION['pageNumber'])) {
  $_SESSION['pageNumber'] = 1;
} else {
  $_SESSION['pageNumber']++;
}
```

In your HTML you can echo it with:

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>You are visiting page <?php echo $_SESSION['pageNumber']; ?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem I was having turned out to be parsing HTML code as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but simply like this?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION[$pagenum]))
{
    //New user
    $_SESSION[$pagenum] = 1;   
}

$_SESSION[$pagenum]++; 

?>

<h1><?php echo $_SESSION[$pagenum] ?></h1>
```

same in the title:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Comment: I want the users to see a line of text at the top of the page that increments each time they are redirected, i.e. Page 1, Page 2, and so on, even though the pages are redirected randomly.